# How does QT get the ico of a process

Tags: qt

I want to make a process list window, so I traverse the process list, but I don’t know how to get the icon and display it in the listWidget

This is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>

    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0);
    if( hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
        pe.dwSize = sizeof(pe);
        if( Process32First(hSnap, &pe) )
        {
            DWORD curID = GetCurrentThreadId();
            do{
                if(pe.th32ProcessID && pe.th32ProcessID != curID)
                {
                    QListWidgetItem *it = new QListWidgetItem(
                                /* icon */

                                PaddingZero(QString::number(pe.th32ProcessID, 16)).toUpper() +"-"+ QString::fromWCharArray(pe.szExeFile),
                                ui->listWidget
                    );
                    ui->listWidget->addItem(it);
                    //printf("name: %ls, id: %d\n",pe.szExeFile,pe.th32ProcessID);
                }
            }while( Process32Next(hSnap, &pe) );
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
```

How can I get the ico of each process.

Comment: I think you should find the binary associated with the process and extract the icon from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, I finally found the answer

```cpp
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0);
    if( hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 pe;
        pe.dwSize = sizeof(pe);
        if( Process32First(hSnap, &pe) )
        {
            do{
                if(pe.th32ProcessID != GetCurrentProcessId())
                {
                    // https://forum.qt.io/topic/62866/getting-icon-from-external-applications/5
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63653786/error-using-getmodulefilenameexa-function-in-qt?noredirect=1#comment112561229_63653786

                    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe.th32ProcessID);
                    wchar_t lpFilename[1024];
                    GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, lpFilename, sizeof(lpFilename));
                    CloseHandle(hProcess);

                    QFileInfo  fin( QString::fromWCharArray(lpFilename) );
                    QFileSystemModel *model = new QFileSystemModel;
                    model->setRootPath(fin.path());
                    QIcon ic = model->fileIcon(model->index(fin.filePath()));

                    QListWidgetItem *it = new QListWidgetItem(
                                ic,
                                PaddingZero(QString::number(pe.th32ProcessID, 16)).toUpper() +
                                "-" +
                                QString::fromWCharArray(pe.szExeFile),
                                ui->list
                                );
                    ui->list->addItem(it);
                    //printf("name: %ls, id: %d\n",pe.szExeFile,pe.th32ProcessID);
                }
            }while( Process32Next(hSnap, &pe) );
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
```