# Error using GetModuleFileNameExA function in Qt

Tags: qt, winapi

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, 7632);
    wchar_t lpFilename[1024];
    GetModuleFileNameExW(hProcess, NULL, lpFilename, sizeof(lpFilename));
    qDebug() << QString::fromWCharArray(lpFilename);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
```

The above code runs normally in vs2019, but when I use it wrong in qt, this error occurs:

```
error: undefined reference to `GetModuleFileNameExA'
error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: See the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexa#remarks) for `GetModuleFileNameExA`, specifically the part about `PSAPI_VERSION` and which `.lib` to link.

Comment: You don't need `PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS` (as [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexa)). But you *do* need to call the Unicode API. Unless you are fine with an implementation that sometimes doesn't fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to load Psapi.lib

Add in the `<project name>.pro` file

```
...

LIBS += \
    -lPsapi

...
```

Comment: you not need use `GetModuleFileNameExA` at all. this is wrong api for your target. you need use `QueryFullProcessImageName`